# Proving $A \cup B$ with the help of axioms

Tags: probability

I need to prove that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

How do you prove this with the help of axioms?  Also, can anyone suggest books where I could look through proofs of axioms and proofs of properties derived from axioms.

Comment: What axioms do you have? Are you looking at probability from a measure theoretic standpoint?

Comment: @DonThousand The standard ones: probability of sample space = 1, probability is non-negative and the additive over the union one.

Comment: Then yea, the duplicate linked should help.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have no clue about what P(A - B) even mean. My study is restricted to the mention of the three axioms above.

Comment: That is just notation. $A-B = A \cap B^c$.

Answer (score 1):

A rigorous proof of the statement $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ is performed using not only the axioms of probability theory **but also the identities of set theory and the axioms of real numbers** (see formal proof below). Unfortunately, if you do not have an understanding of the basics of set theory (including the definition of set, subset, union, intersection, complement, and the various set identities), then you won't be able to grasp a rigorous proof of the above statement. Instead, you will have to rely on your intuition to make sense of it. What follows is a (very) informal proof to help with your understanding as well as a formal proof in case you want more rigor.

INFORMAL PROOF:

[image]

Imagine all the possible outcomes of your probability experiment are contained in the set $S$, the sample space. As you can see above, sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$, and there is even some overlap between the two, indicating that they have some outcomes in common (these outcomes are located in the space labelled $A \cap B$). The $P(A)$ is the probability that the result of the experiment will match one of the outcomes in $A$, and the $P(B)$ is the probability that the result of the experiment will match one of the outcomes in $B$. We want to know the the $P(A \cup B)$, which is the probability that that result of the experiment will match one of the outcomes in $A$, $B$, or both. Axiom iii of modern probability theory says we can determine this by simply adding $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ - but only if sets $A$ and $B$ do not have any outcomes in common. If they do have outcomes in common, then we need to perform one additional step. If we begin by adding $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, notice that we immediately run into a problem: we have added the probabilities of outcomes in $A \cap B$ twice! To rectify this, we subtract the probabilities of outcomes located in this space once, and that's it! Hence, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Note that the statement holds true even if sets $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. In that case, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)=P(A) + P(B) - 0=P(A) + P(B)$, which is true by Axiom iii of probability theory.

FORMAL PROOF:

PROVE: For any arbitrary probability experiment consisting of a finite sample space, $S$, and events $A$ and $B$ s.t. $A \subseteq S$ and $B \subseteq S$, the following is true: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

---

$1$. Let $S$ be the finite sample space of some arbitrary probability experiment with events $A$ and $B$ s.t. $A \subseteq S$ and $B \subseteq S$. First, we show $P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup (B \cap A^C))$.

$A \cup B = (A \cup B) \cap S$ by the identity law, where $S$, the sample space, is our universal set

$= (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup A^C)$ by the negation law

$= A \cup (B \cap A^C)$ by the distributive law

Hence, $A \cup B = A \cup (B \cap A^C)$; thus, we know

**(1)** $P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup (B \cap A^C))$

---

$2$. Second, we show the sets $A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are mutually exclusive or "disjoint" - or in other words, that $A \cap (B \cap A^C)=\emptyset$ where $\emptyset$ is the empty set.

$A \cap (B \cap A^C)=A \cap (A^C \cap B)$ by the commutative law

$=(A \cap A^C) \cap B$ by the associative law

$=\emptyset \cap B$ by the negation law

$=\emptyset$ by the domination law

Hence, $A \cap (B \cap A^C)=\emptyset$, implying that sets $A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are disjoint.

---

$3$. Since $A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are disjoint, then by the finite additvity axiom (axiom iii of modern probability theory) we may conclude $P(A \cup (B \cap A^C))=P(A) + P(B \cap A^C)$. Then, by substitution with equation **(1)**, we have

**(2)** $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B \cap A^C)$.

---

$4$. Next, we show $P(B)=P((B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C))$.

$B=B \cap S$ by the identity law

$=B \cap (A \cup A^C)$ by the negation law

$=(B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C)$ by the distribution law

Hence, $B=(B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C)$; thus, we know

**(3)** $P(B)=P((B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C))$

---

$5$. Now we show that sets $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are disjoint - or in other words, that $(B \cap A) \cap (B \cap A^C)=\emptyset$.

$(B \cap A) \cap (B \cap A^C)=B \cap (A \cap A^C)$ by the distributive law

$=B \cap \emptyset$ by the negation law

$=\emptyset$ by the domination law

Hence, $(B \cap A) \cap (B \cap A^C)=\emptyset$, implying that sets $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are disjoint.

---

$6$. Since $B \cap A$ and $B \cap A^C$ are disjoint, then by the finite additvity axiom we may conclude $P((B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C))=P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^C)$. Then, by substitution with equation **(3)**, we have $P(B)=P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^C)$.

$\Rightarrow P(B) - P(B \cap A)=P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^C) - P(B \cap A)$ by the subtraction property of equality

$\Rightarrow P(B) - P(B \cap A)= P(B \cap A^C) + P(B \cap A) - P(B \cap A)$ by the commutative law for addition

$\Rightarrow P(B) - P(B \cap A)= P(B \cap A^C) + 0$ by the additive inverse law

$\Rightarrow P(B)-P(B \cap A)=P(B \cap A^C)$ by the additive identity law. Then, by the reflexive property of equality, we have

**(4)** $P(B \cap A^C)=P(B)-P(B \cap A)$

---

$7$. By equation **(2)** we know $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B \cap A^C)$, and by equation **(4)** we know $P(B \cap A^C)=P(B)-P(B \cap A)$. By substitution with equations **(2)** and **(4)**, we have $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(B \cap A)$.

---

$8$. Thus, if events $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a finite sample space of some arbitrary probability experiment, then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)-P(B \cap A)$.

---

$\therefore$ For any arbitrary probability experiment consisting of a finite sample space, $S$, and events $A$ and $B$ s.t. $A \subseteq S$ and $B \subseteq S$, the following is true: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Q.E.D.

**BOOK RECOMMENDATIONS**

-Discrete Mathematics and its Applications, 7th ed., by Kenneth H. Rosen. Chapters 1,2,7 for an introduction to logic, proofs, set theory, and discrete probability.

-A First Course in Probability, 9th ed., by Sheldon Ross. Chapter2 and introduction to axioms and foundations of probability theory.

-A Concise Introduction to Logic, llth ed., by Patrick J. Hurley. Chapters 6,7,8 for introduction to propositional logic, natural deduction, and predicate logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's sufficient to note that:

$$A \cup B = (A-B) \cup (B-A) \cup (A \cap B)$$

This is a disjoint union. So:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A-B) + P(B-A) + P(A \cap B)$$

Moreover, the following unions are also disjoint:

$$
A= (A-B) \cup (A \cap B) \ \mbox{and} \ B= (B-A) \cup (A \cap B)
$$

Then:

$$P(A) = P(A-B) + P(A\cap B) \ \mbox{and} \ P(B) = P(B-A) + P(A\cap B)$$

Whence follows the result.

Comment: What does A - B mean?

Comment: $A-B =\{x \in A: x \notin B  \} $

Comment: Could you state in words? I'm a beginner in probability theory.

Comment: It's the elements of A that aren't in B

Comment: So, can you say it is A intersection B complement?

Comment: Exactly. $A-B = A \cap B^c$

Comment: $x \in A$ \ $B$ !